# handle empty strings at array.sort(?) callback in chrome is very slow

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome, sorting, is-empty

in js i have to sort a lot of array elements(100k-1kk).
İn production its possible to have many **blank** ('') strings.

in my sort function i handle empty values - so that this values always come last .its ok.. until i **have** many null or undefined or blank('') values **in data**

**if data have many nulls for example  or blank strings performance is veeery slow.**

And the main thing is that this fragment very slow at **Chrome** (at least last version for now  49.0.2623.110 m)

firefox(45.0.1)  works very well (even with **standart case** without empty data my test x10 faster ??)
just test.with chrome and firefox

P.S. i know jsperf is more preferable for that.anyway

https://jsfiddle.net/3h0gtLu2/18/

```
data = []

var i = 0;

while (i++ <1000){

    data.push('' + i)
}

while (i++ < 20000){

    data.push(''+i  )

}

var start = window.performance.now()
data.sort(function(a,b){

   if (a == null || a == undefined)
                        return 1;
   else if ( b == null || b == undefined)
                        return -1;
   return  (parseInt(a) - parseInt(b));
})

$('#time0').html($('#time0').html() + (window.performance.now() - start))


data = []

var i = 0;

while (i++ <1000){

    data.push('' + i)
}

while (i++ < 20000){

    data.push(null  )

}

var start = window.performance.now()
data.sort(function(a,b){

   if (a == '' || a === null || a == undefined)
                        return 1;
   else if ( a == '' || b === null || b == undefined)
                        return -1;
   return  (parseInt(a) - parseInt(b));
})


$('#time1').html($('#time1').html() + (window.performance.now() - start))


data = []

var i = 0;

while (i++ <1000){

    data.push('' + i)
}

while (i++ < 20000){

    data.push(''  )

}

var start = window.performance.now()
data.sort(function(a,b){

   if ( a == null || a == undefined)
                        return 1;
   else if ( b == null || b == undefined)
                        return -1;
   return  (parseInt(a) - parseInt(b));
})

$('#time2').html($('#time2').html() +( window.performance.now() - start))

data = []

var i = 0;

while (i++ <1000){

  data.push('' + i)
}

while (i++ < 20000){

  data.push(''  )

}

var start = window.performance.now()
data.sort(function(a,b){

   if (a == '' || a == null || a == undefined)
                        return 1;
   else if (b == '' || b == null || b == undefined)
                        return -1;
   return  (parseInt(a) - parseInt(b));
})
$('#time3').html($('#time3').html() +( window.performance.now() - start))
```

Comment: If you don't post the code, it's unlikely anyone can help.

Comment: sorry code posted :)

Comment: The problem is that your sort comparison function is inconsistent, and that can cause the sort algorithm to go crazy. For the same two values, your comparator must always return exactly the same answer.

Comment: but i cant see where comparator return different result for same values.then what i have to do if i want to 'empty always at last' and if many data is empty?

Comment: What if both values are empty? *edit* I guess in this case it's not that aspect of the function, but the fact that you don't handle the case where both values are empty.

Comment: It'd just take a quick edit to give it a try, at least.

Comment: i add condition to beginning a==b return 0. and it seems like worked!

Comment: Wow playing with your fiddle Chrome really is a *lot* slower than Firefox, no matter what I try. That's really weird. *edit* oh wait no I just hadn't scrolled down and seen all the other `.sort()` calls :)

Comment: [Here is an updated version of the fiddle that runs fast in both Chrome and Firefox.](https://jsfiddle.net/tjvey7u9/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to ensure that your comparator will always return a logical answer for every pair of values, you'll have to add the case for when *both* values are empty:

```
data.sort(function(a,b){  
   var anull = (a == '' || a == null), bnull = (b == '' || b == null);
   if (anull && bnull)
     return 0;
   if (anull)
     return 1;
   if (bnull)
     return -1;
   return  (parseInt(a) - parseInt(b));
})
```

Note that you don't need an explicit compare to both `null` and `undefined`; comparing `== null` is exactly the same as comparing `=== null` and `=== undefined`.

My making sure you tell the sort algorithm that when both values are empty they can be left alone (by returning `0`), you avoid it thrashing back and forth in some weird cases.

Another thing that might speed things up would be to make a single pass through the array to convert all the empty entries to some single value (maybe `null`; doesn't matter) and all the non-empty entries to actual numbers. That way your sort won't be paying the price of converting the strings to numbers over and over again (that is, all the calls to `parseInt()`). If you want the array to be strings, you can always convert it back in a subsequent single pass.